# cancer survivor and fitness

Tags: fitness

I am a two-time cancer survivor ...head/neck and lung (they removed a lobe in the second instance) ... I have been biking for a couple of years now (I bought a fixie, since it was cheap and I wasn't sure I would be able to cut it), and I try to ride three or four times a week, but in the range of 5-8 miles each session.  I like to think this is helpful in terms of overall fitness and breathing, but haven't found anything to confirm this. Always trying to expand on distance, but so far stuck in this range.
 Thoughts?

Comment: I don't think you should ask here: it's more like a medical question, and here you risk to get a quite dangerous answers, based on someone's experience, but not on medicine. Glad that your cancer has gone!

Comment: I agree, this is a question best suited for training, etc. The fact you survived cancer doesn't have a strong bearing on this. Members state some "unusual" believes. I think you'd best be served by getting clearance from your doctor, and finding a group to ride with that is beginner friendly.

Comment: The only answer is ride more.  Everything else is circumstances.

Comment: Cycling is an excellent exercise for many situations, since it is relatively "low impact" for the amount of aerobic energy expended.  But expending aerobic energy implies breathing, and there is the danger that cycling intensely could somehow cause you to "over-breathe", given your limited lung capacity.  So it would be wise to check with your doctors before ramping up your efforts too much.  Until you become more comfortable with the situation and verify it with the docs, it's probably best to increase the *duration* of your sessions, vs working too much on increasing *intensity*.

Comment: Leave the question open folks. Just because the OP mentions cancer doesn't make it medical advice question. Of course medical advice is needed also, but it's mainly a training question.

Answer (score 2):

A perfectly reasonable question.

Cycling is gererally thought of as being an excellent way of keeping fit. It is seen as beneficial for cardio- health and for leg muscles (not so much for arms), and is low-impact on joints. On top of that I would add that the benefits are proportional to the amount of effort you put into it.

Of course, how safe this exercise is for the individual would depend on the individual themselves, their existing fitness etc. and any pre-existing medical conditions. An individual should discuss any proposed fitness regime with their doctor. So where your question becomes impossible to answer is how reasonable your fitness regime is for *you*, and any improvements you could make. But that holds true across the board.

Answer (score 2):

In general, when we become "stuck" at a given performance level, the key is to take a different training approach. As a statement of the obvious, what you're doing isn't giving the results you want so something's got to change.

I suspect that you are over training. While you and many others would see the distances you're riding as quite low, the inability to progress is a key symptom.

So I recommend three things.

First, reduce the intensity of your rides. Try to ride somewhere flat, where you can just cruise along at an easy pace.

Second, at that easy pace, ride further. You might trick your body by riding 5 miles (8 km) to meet a friend for coffee, then ride home afterwards.

Thirdly only ride every second day at the most. Give your body time to recover and for your muscles and organs to develop in between rides.

As a non-fixie rider, I suspect that the fixie is part of the problem, because riding a fixed wheel bike is so exhilarating and immediate. Even changing to a single speed, perhaps via a flip flop hub, could help reduce the intensity. The other way to go would be to switch to a normal road bike.

Of course, on a site such as this, we need to say (a little patronisingly perhaps) that this is not medical advice. But you knew that :-)

Keep at it!

Answer (score -1):

The human body is amazing
Although cancer is a tragedy, but in the face of pain, be sure to maintain a happy mood
Cycling is a very good event, it does make people happy life. Riding in the process can be a lot of insight into the views, it is also conducive to thinking, which for your disease will be a good help.
Please keep a happy mood every day, bless you

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! This is a site that tries to maintain a focused question and answer format, rather than collection of broad, free-ranging thread like you might see in a typical forum. For an intro to how this and other Stack Exchange Q & A sites work, please [Take the Tour](//bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour).